# How to save a file programmatically in internal storage (visible)

Tags: android, file, programming-languages, save

I'm developing an app and want to save two variables `String s, Integer i`  in a readable and writable file in the internal storage `/sdcard/Android/data/<App-Path>/files/myfile.txt`, when you press an  `Exit-Button`. And I want to open the file and get the values of the variables when the app starts. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: /sdcard/Android/data/ is not internal storage??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/sdcard/Android/data/ is not internal storage...its external..

you should ask it to google first anyways here's what you need

[Using Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

and if you want to save files in SD card use [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: i have provided you with the link you need just go through it and try it on your own first if you face any problem post the code..we are here to help :)

Comment: you can accept an answer if it helped you by Clicking the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [android guide to internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

You need to add permission to access the SD-card see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html), and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). Look for

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

For full details on accessing external storage, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: yups, thats why i gavee him both answers @Shiv